# Regex: найти атрибуты, игнорируя атрибуты в значениях

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте!

Как с помощью Regex найти атрибуты в строке? Но строка не простая, в ней также как в Xaml, атрибуты могут быть указаны внутри кавычек. Такие атрибуты надо игнорировать.
Например, для следующей строки: (похоже на XML, но он невалидный, потому что в строке нет скобок `<` и `>`)

`Tag a1 = " calibri 15  "   a2= "{v2 path=ss, conv=ss}"   width=*   x:a3="v3"  b="... FA= fv FB = fv "     a4.a5="a45"`

надо получить следующие подстроки:

- `calibri 15`
- `{v2 path=ss, conv=ss}`
- `*`
- `v3`
- `... FA= fv FB = fv`
- `a45`

Помогите, пожалуйста, написать регулярное выражение для такого поиска.
В документации сказано, что в Regex можно задать правило для игнорирования определенных последовательностей. Это можно сделать с помощью: `(?<name>)`, `(?<-name>)` и `(?(name)`, но как применить в моем случае не знаю.

Comment: Для того, чтобы парсить XML, нужно пользоваться XML-парсером. Регулярки для этого не предназначены.

Comment: Это невалидный XML, потому что в нем нет скобок, которыми выделяются теги.

Comment: А если вы пытаетесь распарсить XAML (на это намекает имя шрифта и синтаксис типа `{Binding Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource conv}}`), вам нужен скорее всего [`XamlReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlreader.aspx).

Comment: Ну так вы его откуда-то взяли? То, откуда вы выкусили эту подстроку, и был XML.

Comment: Взял из файла, но это не XML и оригинального XML не было и нет.

Comment: А покажите весь файл, если он небольшой. А если большой, то первые строк 10 покажите.

Comment: Строки в файле похожи на ту, что в вопросе. Только слова разные, например, вместо Tag - Sensor12, а вместо атрибутов a1 и a2 - entry1 и entry2 соответственно и так далее. Чтобы было понятно, это файл для записи логов работы сенсоров. Записано безобразно, но ничего поделать не могу, надо разобраться.

Comment: Т.е. каждый Tag на своей строке, так?

Comment: Tag один в строке в самом начале, поэтому его можно игнорировать.

Comment: Это я понял, но на одной строке только один Tag? Т.е. каждый Tag на новой строке?

Comment: Да, только один Tag в строке.

Answer (score 1):

Я понимаю, что Вы спрашиваете про регулярные выражения, а моё решение их не использует. Тем не менее, на мой взгляд моё решение куда проще, чем игра с регулярками.

Небольшие условия, для работоспособности нижеизложенного решения:

1. Нужно установить nuget пакет HtmlAgilityPack - это важно
2. Код использует C#6 — это не важно и можно без этого обойтись.

Суть моего решения такова:

- Сначала мы из файла вычитаем все строки, и каждую строку обернём в угловые скобки, чтобы превратить их в натуральные теги.
- Затем обернём наши строки в `<html>` и скормим полученную строку HtmlAgilityPack
- После этого мы можем потреблять наши атрибуты и теги, так, как нам нужно.

Вот пример того, о чём я говорю:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

namespace CSharpExp
{
    class Program
    {
        static IEnumerable<string> GetRawString()
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
                yield return @"Tag a1 = "" calibri 15  ""   a2= ""{ v2 path = ss, conv = ss}""   width =*   x:a3=""v3""  b =""...FA = fv FB = fv ""     a4.a5=""a45""";
        }

        static string StringToTag(string input)
        {
            return "<" + input + "/>";
        }

        static string PrepareData()
        {
            var tags = GetRawString().Select(StringToTag);
            return String.Join("\n", tags);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            HtmlDocument document = new HtmlDocument();
            string htmlString = $"<html>{PrepareData()}</html>";
            document.LoadHtml(htmlString);
            var tags = document.DocumentNode.Descendants();
            foreach(var tag in tags)
            {
                if(tag.HasAttributes)
                {
                    foreach(var attribute in tag.Attributes)
                        Console.Write($"{{{attribute.Name}={attribute.Value}}}");
                    Console.WriteLine();    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`GetRawString` - имитирует тот код, который Вы будете использовать при чтении файла, просто генерация 10-и одинаковых строк. Остальное должно быть понятно, если нет — спрашивайте.

Comment: может тогда проще после оборачивания в `<>` как xml читать?

Comment: @Grundy, там невалидный XML, у некоторых атрибутов нет кавычек

Comment: да, про это что-то не подумал:)